# proving dimention of a eigenspace is 1?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors

If

$\hspace{2in}$$ J = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda & 1 \\
& \lambda & 1 \\
& & \ddots & \ddots \\
& & & \lambda & 1 \\
& & & & \lambda
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathsf{M}_n,$

prove that $ \dim(\mathsf{N}(J - \lambda I_n)) = 1$

For my proof i said that $\dim(N(J-\lambda I_n)) = \dim(E_{\lambda})$ (and then i got stuck)

$\hspace{10mm}$I said that because i was under the assumption that $ E_\lambda=N(\lambda I_n−A)$, because $ Ax=\lambda x$. But after getting to this point i feel like i cannot end up with one as my answer. What should i do? How would i solve this?

Comment: I assume $N$ means the (right) nullspace. What are $E_\lambda$ and $E$?

Comment: $E_{\lambda}$ is the eigenspace of $\lambda$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
J-\lambda I_n = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
& 0 & 1 \\
& & \ddots & \ddots \\
& & & 0 & 1 \\
& & & & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Thus $\dim(E_\lambda)=\dim(N(J-\lambda I_n))=1$.

Comment: why did all of the $\lambda$s turn into zeros?

Comment: Because we subtracted $\lambda I_n$ from $J$ and $\lambda I_n$ is the $n\times n$ matrix with $\lambda$'s on the diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

You're overcomplicating things; $J - \lambda I_n$ is already in reduced row echelon form, so the basics tell you everything you want to know about solutions to the linear system of equations $(J - \lambda I_n) x = 0$.